# highlighting messages in output window

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-studio-2010

I saw a screencast recently and what really got me interested is that messages in debugger output window were displayed in different colours (different color for warnings, exceptions etc).Unfrotunately I can't find this screencast anymore.

Does anyone know if this is a new feature of VS2010 or is it part of 2008 and just need turning on?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it's only available for Visual Studio 2010, since it uses WPF. Custom formatting for the Debug output window is possible with the [*VSCommands*](http://vscommands.com/features/) extension.

Comment: more and more reasons to upgrade to 2010 it seems :)

Answer (score 5):

It would be pretty easy to do as an extension, if you are interested:

1. Start with the [Diff Classifier](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/diffclassifier) sample.
2. Change the [ContentType] attribute in DiffClassifierProvider.cs to "output".
3. Delete the `ContentTypeDefinition` and `FileExtensionToContentTypeDefinition` exports from 
   DiffClassificationDefinitions.cs.
4. Add/modify the `ClassificationTypeDefinition` and `ClassificationFormatDefinition` exports for the formatting you want to apply.

Comment: Great answer! It took me less than 5 min to do it with some sample output coloring :)) Thx mate :)

Answer (score 4):

This may be useful VSColorOutput (open source)

http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f4d9c2b5-d6d7-4543-a7a5-2d7ebabc2496